# Text '28Feb2020' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 7

Tags: java, date, java-time, date-parsing, datetimeparseexception

Input Text is 20FEB2020

The following code block throws a `DateTimeParseException` with the message *Text '28Feb2020' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 7*:

```
String issueDate = abcIssueDate.substring(0, 3)
                  + abcIssueDate.substring(3).toLowerCase();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMyy", Locale.US);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(issueDate, formatter);
```

Comment: `yy` should be `yyyy`?

Comment: Not answering your question, rather than fixing the case of `Feb` by hand, use a `DateTImeFormatterBuilder` to specify case insensitive parsing.

Comment: I am not sure where you are stuck here. The pattern clearly does not match the input, which is very easy to spot at the very first glance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 DateTimeFormatter two digit year 18 parsed to 0018 instead of 2018?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156022/java-8-datetimeformatter-two-digit-year-18-parsed-to-0018-instead-of-2018) Not the exact same question, but the answers could be helpful to you too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I upvoted because I found the question and the problem clear and very answerable. My guess is that the downvotes are from users who found the question poorly searched and researched. [Guideline #1 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says search and research before posting your question.

Answer (score 2):

The exception your code block throws is very likely to be caused by the pattern of your `DateTimeFormatter`. As already commented below your question, you are using two `y` for a year that has 4 digits.
So you could change the pattern to `"ddMMMyyyy"`, which might work.

Also, I strongly recommend you to build and use a `DateTimeFormatter` with `DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseCaseInsensitive` that parses the input string case-insensitively:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String time = "20FEB2020";
    // build a DateTimeFormatter that parses case-insensitively
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                    .appendPattern("ddMMMuuuu")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(time, dtf);
    System.out.println(localDate);
}
```

The result is (implicitly using the `toString()` method of `LocalDate`):

```
2020-02-20
```

Comment: In particular upvoted for the demonstration of `.parseCaseInsensitive()`. It gives much nicer code.